# Skia SkCanvas cannot be constructed with SkBitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap, skia

I have a draw(SkCanvas* canvas) function.

In main() I write:

```
SkBitmap myBitmap;
myBitmap.allocN32Pixels(640, 480);

SkCanvas *myCanvas(&myBitmap);
draw(myCanvas);
```

But Visual Studio generates this error:

> ```
> "a value of type "SkBitmap *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "SkCanvas*"
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

My draw() function clutters the post and is completely useless for this question otherwise I've posted it.

This is the construction for SkCanvas.

```
/** Construct a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into.
        @param bitmap   Specifies a bitmap for the canvas to draw into. Its
                        structure are copied to the canvas.
    */
explicit SkCanvas(const SkBitmap& bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SkCanvas *myCanvas(&myBitmap);
```

this is a pointer to a canvas.  The pointer types of `SkCanvas*` and `SkBitmap*` are unrelated.

```
SkCanvas myCanvas(&myBitmap);
```

this is a value of type `myCanvas`, initialized with a pointer to bitmap.  If `SkCanvas` has a ctor taking a `SkBitmap*`, this should work.

It does not.  It does have:

```
explicit SkCanvas(const SkBitmap& bitmap);
```

so this means:

```
SkCanvas myCanvas(myBitmap);
```

You'll probably also need to change the draw call to this:

```
draw(&myCanvas);
```

assuming that works.  As a guess, you also need a refresher on the difference between pointers and values.

Comment: It only solved half of my problem. The "Constructor does not match" error still persists.

Comment: @aurk you also misread the canvas bitmap constructor.  Fixed.